# Interface não respondendo após transição de janelas - PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, gui, pysimplegui

Olá, estou fazendo uma interface com PySimpleGUI para um chat que estou desenvolvendo, meu problema é que após sair da primeira tela nenhum botão das telas subsequentes funciona, alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu esteja fazendo de errado?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
#import servidor as sv

def jn_usuario():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Insira seu apelido:')],
        [sg.InputText(key = 'usuario')],
        [sg.Button('Ok')]
    ]
    return sg.Window('Chat TCP', layout, finalize = True)

def jn_chat(nome_usuario):
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Olá, ' + nome_usuario)],
        [sg.Text('Insira um IP para se conectar:'), sg.Button('Conectar', key = '-CONEX-')],
        [sg.InputText(key = '-IP-'), sg.Button('Hospedar conversa', key = '-HOST-')],
        [sg.Multiline(size = (60,20), disabled = True)],
        [sg.InputText(key = 'mensagem'), sg.Button('Enviar')],
    ]
    return sg.Window('Chat TCP', layout, finalize = True)

def jn_host(nome_usuario):
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Este é o servidor do ' + nome_usuario)],
        [sg.Multiline(size = (60,20), disabled = True)],
        [sg.Button('Encerrar Conexão', key = '-FIM_CONEX-')],
    ]
    return sg.Window('Chat TCP', layout, finalize = True)

def main():
    janela_usuario, janela_chat, janela_host = jn_usuario(),None, None
    while True:
        window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if window == janela_usuario and event == 'Ok':
            if(values['usuario'] == ''):
                sg.Popup('Insira um apelido válido')
            else:
                janela_chat = jn_chat(values['usuario'])
                janela_usuario.hide()
            if window == janela_chat and event == 'Enviar':
                print('mensagem') #NAO PRINTA#
            if window == janela_chat and event == '-CONEX-':
                pass
            if window == janela_chat and event == '-HOST-':
                janela_host = jn_host(values['usuário'])
                janela_chat.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que o problema está na indentação do seu código, que está fazendo com que as condições dentro do loop while só sejam executadas quando o usuário insere um nome de usuário. Tente corrigir a indentação do seu código de acordo com o exemplo abaixo, onde as condições são executadas sempre que houver um evento em qualquer janela:

```
def main():
    janela_usuario, janela_chat, janela_host = jn_usuario(),None, None
    while True:
        window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        if window == janela_usuario and event == 'Ok':
            if(values['usuario'] == ''):
                sg.Popup('Insira um apelido válido')
            else:
                janela_chat = jn_chat(values['usuario'])
                janela_usuario.hide()

        if window == janela_chat and event == 'Enviar':
            print('mensagem') # Agora deverá printar

        if window == janela_chat and event == '-CONEX-':
            pass

        if window == janela_chat and event == '-HOST-':
            janela_host = jn_host(values['usuario'])
            janela_chat.hide()
```

Além disso, o parâmetro "key" do seu layout na função "jn_host" está escrito como "usuário", mas nas outras funções está escrito como "usuario" (sem acento). Tenha certeza de que está utilizando a mesma chave em todas as janelas.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).